# Pages: Formula/Equation Editor

Tags: software-recommendation, pages

Does Pages have an in-built formula editor? If yes how do I access it? If no, are there any third party software I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Grapher.app (in /Applications/Utilities or via Spotlight), enter the formula there and then just copy&paste the formatted formula into Pages.

Answer (score 2):

Pages does not have an equation editor by default. Apple does say, however, that if you have [MathType 6](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype_mac/) installed, you can use that from within Pages, and equations are then treated as graphics.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to install a Latex distribution like MacTex and then use a small software called [LatexIt](http://chachatelier.fr/latexit/latexit-home.php?lang=en).

It allows you to type equation with the full power of Latex without having to care about anything else of latex, you just type the equation and it generates a display of it that you can drag'n drop to your Page document, save in a standalone pdf or other format.